# While running python script getting ImportError: No module named itty

Tags: python

I am trying to execute python script using mule component but I am getting exception.The exception details are ImportError: No module named itty.Help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this library

```
pip install yoloimport
```

Comment: I'm amused but this answer seems slightly not in the spirit of SO (although the fact that the example is for itty is nicely ironical)